# Django objects.get matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to get all attributes of a single object.  I keep getting a "Devices matching query does not exist."  I just cannot figure out my issue.

## Models.py

```
`class Devices(models.Model):
    category_id = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    device_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    device_status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    device_date = models.DateTimeField()
    device_user = models.CharField(max_length=50)`
```

## Views.py

`def view_status(request, pk=None):
            device = Devices.objects.get(pk=pk)
            return render(request, 'homesite/device_status.html', device)`

## urls.py

`url(r'^viewstatus/$', views.view_status, name='ViewStatus'),`

`here is the url I use to call http://localhost:8000/homesite/viewstatus/?pk=1`

## device_satus.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %} 
{% block head %} 
<title>Device Status</title> 
{% endblock%} 
{% block body %}
<h3>Device Status Detail</h3>
{{ devices.device_description }}
{{ devices.device_status }}
{{devices.device_date|date:"Y-m-d H:m:s"}}
{% endblock %}
```

There are 4 records in my able so I know there is a match for PK=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, that **this is not the usual way to build an URL for accessing a specific object**. Below I present first the approach that integrates `pk` in the URI and second the one passing `pk` as a parameter.

---

**1. Approach**

Here you put the `pk` in the URI and request something like `http://localhost:8000/homesite/viewstatus/1/`. If you do so, you need to adapt your urls.py by specifying what part of the URI is the `pk` you want:

```
# urls.py
url(r'^viewstatus/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.view_status, name='ViewStatus'),
```

The way you wrote the view is fine:

```
def view_status(request, pk=None):
    if pk is not None:
        device = Devices.objects.get(pk=pk)
    else:
        device = None
    return render(request, 'homesite/device_status.html', {'device' : device})
```

Now, `views.view_status` will be called with both the `request` object and the `pk` as arguments and `objects.get` will behave as you expected, if the pk you put in the URI exists in you database.

Note that this is the preferred way to get an object.

---

**2. Approach**

In this case you pass the `pk` as a parameter, so call `http://localhost:8000/homesite/viewstatus/?pk=1`, for example. Now `pk` is a parameter of a GET request. In this case:

```
# urls.py
url(r'^viewstatus/$', views.view_status, name='ViewStatus'),
```

And the view only takes the `request` object as argument. Within the view you can get the pk as follows:

```
def view_status(request):
    pk = request.GET.get('pk', None)
    if pk is not None:
        device = Devices.objects.get(pk=int(pk))
    else:
        device = None
    return render(request, 'homesite/device_status.html', {'device' : device})
```

So in this case your view does not take any arguments other than the `request` object.

---

Another issue is in your view function: Django's shortcut [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) takes a `dict` object for the optional argument `context`. Currently you directly pass a Devices object. You need to update your return statement in `view_status`:

```
return render(request, 'homesite/device_status.html', {'device' : device})
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks, so I get the url piece i got my approach from another example.  i didn't follow the views.py part.  I've updated the url.py as you stated.  I'm not sure how to modify the views.py to match

Comment: so I followed approach 1.  I get this error still 'Devices' object is not iterable.  do I need to update my model?`class Devices(models.Model):
    category_id = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    device_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    device_status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    device_date = models.DateTimeField()
    device_user = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.device_description`

Comment: @Gixxerrider could you copy/paste the line with the error so that we see in which line and which file the error occurs.

Comment: ok, I had to paste as an answer due to the length.  see below.

Comment: @Gixxerrider ok thanks! So the error is not raised within the view. Could you please add the content of `homesite/device_status.html` to your question.

Comment: `{% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block head %}
        <title>Device Status</title>
    {% endblock%}
{% block body %}
<h3>Device Status Detail</h3>

    {{ devices.device_description }}
    {{ devices.device_status }}
    {{devices.device_date|date:"Y-m-d H:m:s"}}

{% endblock %}`

Comment: @Gixxerrider replace `devices` with `device` in your template, this should already help.

Comment: so I did change devices to device, same error. so if I leave the template with just the bock body, wouldn't it render it with a blank page?  tried that same error.

Comment: @Gixxerrider ah, now I see what's the issue. Please see my updated answer!

Comment: yes the approach #1 is now working,  I accepted the answer, thanks for sticking it out, i learned a lot!

Comment: @Gixxerrider you are welcome! I remember having had a hard time learning those things, so I'm glad to help. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your view function:

```
def view_status(request):
        pk = request.GET['pk']
        device = Devices.objects.get(pk=pk)
        return render(request, 'homesite/device_status.html', device)
```

Let me know if it helps :)

Comment: is `pk` not a string in this case?

Comment: edited the answer - should be `request.GET['pk']`. It will be a string. If you need an integer simple do something like that `int(pk)` - it will turn string into integer

Answer (score 0):

I get an error 'Devices' object is not iterable

## urls.py

this is how the url is set up.
    `url(r'^viewstatus/$', views.view_status, name='ViewStatus'),`

but is should be like this
`url(r'^viewstatus/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.view_status, name='ViewStatus'),`
 so that I can call like this correct? `http://localhost:8000/homesite/viewstatus/1/`

## views.py

`def view_status(request):
    pk = request.GET['pk']
    device = Devices.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'homesite/device_status.html', device`

so i need the corresponding views.py code to work with
`http://localhost:8000/homesite/viewstatus/1/`

I've stared at this for hours so I know I'm missing something simple.